"make: *** There is no rule to build target "sub-mysql". Stop." error when trying to create a MySQL driver with Qt
I'm trying to install the QMYSQL driver on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS with Qt version 5.15.3, but I'm running into some issues.
Problem:
The sqldrivers directory only contains the SQLite driver, and I'm missing the QMYSQL driver.
Paths:

qmake: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake
sqldrivers: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers
libmysqlclient.so.21.2.37: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.21.2.37
MySQL headers: /usr/include/mysql

Steps Taken:

Installed necessary dependencies: sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev
Tried the following commands:

bash
cd $QTDIR/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers
qmake -- MYSQL_PREFIX=/usr/local
make sub-mysql
Output:

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers$ qmake -- MYSQL_PREFIX=/usr/include/mysql
Usage: /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake [mode] [options] [files]
QMake has two modes, one mode for generating project files based on
some heuristics, and the other for generating makefiles. Normally you
shouldn't need to specify a mode, as makefile generation is the default
mode for qmake, but you may use this to test qmake on an existing project
[...]

and:

make: *** There is no rule to build target "sub-mysql".  Stop.


How do I solve this problem and install the QMYSQL driver?

You need the Qt sources to compile the Qt mysql driver (how should something gets compiled when there are no sources??)
